# Template Operator []=

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-keyword

As an exercise I am making a template Array class, and I would like to perform this:

```
Array<int> a[5];

a[4] = 2;
```

How do I write such thing?
I've tried:

```
template<class T> class Array{
...
T operator[(const int loc)]=(const T temp);
```

Comment: FYI, preferred practice is to write the concrete class completely before converting to a template.

Comment: Templates aren't really relevant here. This is a question about how to overload `op[]`.

Answer (score 8):

You write an `operator []` which returns a reference to the element. Being a reference, it can be assigned to via `=`.

```
template <typename T>
class Array {
    …
    T& operator [](unsigned int const loc) {
        …
    }
};
```

(The `const` in the argument isn’t commonly used but go ahead and use it in the function’s definition – however, in its *declaration* it makes no sense.)

You usually want another version operator that is `const`, so that you can still *read* values from a `const` array:

```
Array<int> x;
Array<int> const& y = x;

std::cout << y[0]; // Won’t compile!
```

To make the last line compile, add the following code to your class:

```
T const& operator [](unsigned int const loc) const {
    …
}
```

Notice that both the return value as well as the function itself are marked as `const`.

Comment: Thank you,is there any way to make an operator with 2 arguments like I tried above?

Comment: @TaruStolovich No. But there doesn’t need to be.

Comment: @Taru:  There is no way to make a `[]=` operator in C++.  You can't create a new operator, or change associativity or precedence.  You just give a new meaning to an existing one.

Comment: What does the _const_ modifier on the 'loc' argument do? My guess is nothing :-)

Comment: @Martin It makes the argument unmodifiable within the function itself. I prefer to make *all* my variable `const` (except for loop variables and few other exceptions) just to let the compiler catch faulty assignments immediately. I usually never modify variables, I *transform* them, creating new variables to hold the result.

Comment: @Martin: it prevents you from modifying `loc` in the function body. Does not change a thing for the class user, but can help the class writer avoids mistakes.

Comment: @David: Try not to give new meanings to operators. :)

Comment: @Tomalak:  Excellent advice; if I could edit old comments I'd clarify that.  I'd say something like "You just give a new definition to an existing one."  New meanings (like input, output, concatenation) should be done very rarely.

Comment: operator[] can only have one parameter. Use operator() if you want two or more parameters.